# Empty list while scraping Google Search Result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape Google Search Result but all I'm getting as an output is empty list. Do you have any idea what's wrong here? I found the similar post on Stack Overflow where [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62466340/cant-scrape-google-search-results-with-beautifulsoup) says you should try putting user_agent. I tried but it still returns nothing. Please share if you have any idea.

```
import requests, webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_input = input("Enter something to search:")
print("googling.....")

google_search = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+user_input)
# print(google_search.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.text , 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())

search_results = soup.select('.r a')
# print(search_results)

for link in search_results[:5]:
    actual_link = link.get('href')
    print(actual_link)
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com/'+actual_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get results from Google page, you have to specify `User-Agent` http header. For english results, add `hl=en` parameter to search URL:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

user_input = input("Enter something to search: ")
print("googling.....")

google_search = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="+user_input, headers=headers)  # <-- add headers and hl=en parameter

soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.text , 'html.parser')

search_results = soup.select('.r a')

for link in search_results:
    actual_link = link.get('href')
    print(actual_link)
```

Prints:

```
Enter something to search: tree
googling.....
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wHCoEH9G9w8J:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree+&cd=22&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
/search?hl=en&q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree+tree&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmroPTuZLqAhVWWs0KHV4oCtsQHzAVegQIAxAH
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tNzOpY417g8J:https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree+&cd=23&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
/search?hl=en&q=related:https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree+tree&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmroPTuZLqAhVWWs0KHV4oCtsQHzAWegQIARAH
https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:91hg5d2649QJ:https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree+&cd=24&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
/search?hl=en&q=related:https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree+tree&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmroPTuZLqAhVWWs0KHV4oCtsQHzAXegQIAhAJ
https://www.knowablemagazine.org/article/living-world/2018/what-makes-tree-tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AVSszZLtPiQJ:https://www.knowablemagazine.org/article/living-world/2018/what-makes-tree-tree+&cd=25&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
https://teamtrees.org/
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gVbpYoK7meUJ:https://teamtrees.org/+&cd=26&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oyS4e3WdMX8J:https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tree+&cd=27&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:s_tZIjpvHZIJ:https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree+&cd=28&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
/search?hl=en&q=related:https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree+tree&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmroPTuZLqAhVWWs0KHV4oCtsQHzAbegQICBAH
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tree
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EhFIP6m4MuIJ:https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tree+&cd=29&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
https://www.treepeople.org/tree-benefits
#
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4wLYFp4zTuUJ:https://www.treepeople.org/tree-benefits+&cd=30&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
```

---

EDIT: To filter results you can use this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

user_input = input("Enter something to search: ")
print("googling.....")

google_search = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="+user_input, headers=headers)  # <-- add headers and hl=en parameter

soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.text , 'html.parser')

search_results = soup.select('.r a')

for link in search_results:
    actual_link = link.get('href')
    if actual_link.startswith('#') or \
       actual_link.startswith('https://webcache.googleusercontent.com') or \
       actual_link.startswith('/search?'):
        continue
    print(actual_link)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Enter something to search: tree
googling.....
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree
https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree
https://www.knowablemagazine.org/article/living-world/2018/what-makes-tree-tree
https://teamtrees.org/
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tree
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tree
https://www.treepeople.org/tree-benefits
```

Comment: I found where I went wrong ....it was the place to call header...Thank you. But here we are getting two types of links...won't it be possible to get the below one link only?? For ex: Not https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wHCoEH9G9w8J:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree+&cd=22&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sk
/search?hl=en&q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree+tree&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmroPTuZLqAhVWWs0KHV4oCtsQHzAVegQIAxAH  but https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree only??

Comment: Ooh..Tysm...Not a question just asking out of curiosity Do you never tackle with Recaptcha or errors like 429 while scraping google search result ??

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel Never yet, but I haven't needed it yet. I can imagine Google has some protections against mass scrapping search results.

Comment: So lucky...For me Even when I run the above code for more than 2-3 times...I get [ ] empty list because of 429 error.

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel What did you do to fix? You just added the headers line? I am calling headers but it is still returning an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Google blocks your requests and threw this error *This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the [Terms of Service](//www.google.com/policies/terms/). The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.  In the meantime, solving the above CAPTCHA will let you continue to use our services.

This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests.  If you share your network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different computer using the same IP address may be responsible.  [Learn more](//support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640)

Sometimes you may be asked to solve the CAPTCHA if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.*.

Try using selenium + python to get all the links

Answer (score 1):

Most websites nowadays use JavaScript to dynamically load their webpages. Google is one of those websites. In order for the full DOM (document object model) to load in, you need a Javascript engine, which beautifulsoup and requests don't have. Arun recommended selenium, and I do to, as it has an embedded Javascript engine.

Here is the Python Selenium documentation:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

The OP desired output doesn't come from JavaScript as [Serket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62494801/15164646) mentioned. All data that OP needed **is located** in the HTML.

There's no point in `selenium` as well for the same reason, it's all there, in the HTML, **not** rendered via JavaScript.

---

One of the problems as other people mentioned is because of no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) specified AND you *possibly* passed the *wrong* `user-agent` which leads to a completely different HTML that contains an error message or something similar. [Check out what is your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get(YOUR_URL, headers=headers)
```

You can also grab attributes by passing them in square brackets:

```py
element.get('href')
# is equivalent to
element['href']
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py) (*`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)*):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "fus ro dah" # query
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

# container with links and iterate over it
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

-------
'''
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah
https://www.etsy.com/market/fus_ro_dah
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/4889/
https://www.textualtees.com/products/fus-ro-dah-t-shirt
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Search Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't need to figure out why or how to deal with such a problem since this part (*extraction/scraping*) is already done for the end-user. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want.

Code:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "fus ro day",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['link'])

---------
'''
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force
https://www.etsy.com/market/fus_ro_dah
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah
https://www.textualtees.com/products/fus-ro-dah-t-shirt
https://tenor.com/search/fus-ro-dah-gifs
'''
```

P.S - I have a blog post that covers a bit more in-depth how to scrape [Google Organic Search Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.