# Why is BeautifulSoup returning None when scraping google search results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to find the birth years of different authors. I'm working in VS Code, if that's relevant. This is my first attempt at web scraping so please explain things as clearly as possible

For authors with wikipedia pages, I can successully find birth years using the following code:

```
source_code = requests.get("a_wikipedia_url")
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="html.parser")
finder = soup.find("span", {"class": "bday"})
if finder is not None:
        birth_year = finder.string[0:4]
        return birth_year
```

However when I try the same thing with google search for authors with no (English) wikipedia page, I just get None.

After reading this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62466340/cant-scrape-google-search-results-with-beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com) I added a User Agent response header to requests.get (I'm using Chrome Version 114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Windows 11 Home), but all it did was print None instead of giving my AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string', which is what I was getting before adding the header.

This is my code:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5735.134 Safari/537.36"}
source_code = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=Guillermo+Saccomanno", headers=headers)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="html.parser")
google_finder = soup.find("span", {"class": "LrzXr kno-fv wHYlTd z8gr9e"})
print(google_finder.string)
```

The result is just None - no error message, but no text.

I also tried with the header Chrome version as Chrome/114.0.0.0, which is what I found online. Still gives None.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as the syntax is identical and I copied the class name from the page source? For this particular author, I would expect google_finder.string to be "9 June 1948 (age 75 years)".

Comment: Probably because the Google search results page uses a lot of javascript, which the `requests` module does not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the born date I'd chose different strategy: Find a `<span>` tag with text `"Born:"` and then next sibling. Also add `hl=en` parameter to URL to get english results:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Guillermo+Saccomanno&hl=en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

born = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Born:") + span')
print(born.text)
```

Prints:

```
June 9, 1948 (age 75 years), Buenos Aires, Argentina
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selenium` to render the web page first and then search for the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
# Comment to show the window
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

search_query = "Guillermo Saccomanno"
search_url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search_query}"
driver.get(search_url)

google_finder = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "LrzXr")
# You can use any of the classes as long as you make sure that the class is unique: LrzXr kno-fv wHYlTd z8gr9e

result_text = google_finder.text
print(result_text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried this and get the following result:                          
 DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50127/devtools/browser/41478c41-0078-4ac1-8aed-2401aab60f72
[0618/202440.266:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'.", source:  (0)                                                         
  Any ideas?

Comment: It's just a warning, it shouldn't affect the output afterall. If you are getting the desired output but still not wanting to see the warnings, you can use `options.add_argument('--log-level=1')`

Comment: Though now looking at Andrej's reply, it may be better to go with his solution. It's much less resource intensive and much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `googlesearch`

1. install the library: `pip install google`
2. use the code:

```
from googlesearch import search

r = search("something", stop = 20, num = 5, pause = 3) #search for : something

for i in r:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not sure how to use this for my specific problem - it seems to return a list of search results rather than information about birth year? I am running this on a dataframe of several thousand authors so I don't want to have to search through the search results, I just want the year returned in a format I can easily convert into an integer